# Minimal example opencv, pyinstaller, conda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, pyinstaller

I'm trying to get a minimal example working using `pyinstaller` and `opencv` inside a `conda` environment.

So far, what I'm doing is:

```
conda create -n minimal_example python=3 pyinstaller opencv
```

which leaves me with the following packages:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
altgraph                  0.17                       py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
certifi                   2020.6.20                py38_0
future                    0.18.2                   py38_1
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
intel-openmp              2020.1                      216
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
libopencv                 4.0.1                hbb9e17c_0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libtiff                   4.1.0                h56a325e_1
lz4-c                     1.9.2                h62dcd97_0
macholib                  1.11                       py_0
mkl                       2020.1                      216
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.1.0            py38h45dec08_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h47e9c7a_0
numpy                     1.18.5           py38h6530119_0
numpy-base                1.18.5           py38hc3f5095_0
opencv                    4.0.1            py38h2a7c758_0
openssl                   1.1.1g               he774522_0
pefile                    2019.4.18                  py_0
pip                       20.1.1                   py38_1
py-opencv                 4.0.1            py38he44ac1e_0
pycryptodome              3.8.2            py38he774522_0
pyinstaller               3.6              py38h62dcd97_5
python                    3.8.3                he1778fa_0
pywin32                   227              py38he774522_1
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py38_1000
setuptools                47.3.1                   py38_0
six                       1.15.0                     py_0
sqlite                    3.32.3               h2a8f88b_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_2
wheel                     0.34.2                   py38_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
zstd                      1.4.4                ha9fde0e_3
```

I have a script called `minimal_build.py` with the following content:

```
print('Importing numpy')

import numpy as np

print(np.__version__)
print(np.__file__)

print('Importing OpenCV')

import cv2
```

I'm trying to package that script into an executable running

```
pyinstaller minimal_build.py
```

When running the resulting exe, I get the following output:

```
Importing numpy
C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\minimal_example\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:623: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "minimal_build.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\minimal_example\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 235, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\envs\minimal_example\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\mkl\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
  File "mkl\_mkl_service.pyx", line 27, in init mkl._py_mkl_service
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
[9644] Failed to execute script minimal_build
```

So I'm guessing, that it tries to import numpy from my user folder instead of the package. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happened to have the same problem as you

Here is the solution I tried:

```
conda create -n minimal_example python=3.7 pyinstaller
conda activate minimal_example
pip install opencv-python
```

not `conda install opencv`

my conda list:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
altgraph                  0.17                       py_0    defaults
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0    defaults
certifi                   2020.6.20                py37_0    defaults
future                    0.18.2                   py37_1    defaults
macholib                  1.11                       py_0    defaults
numpy                     1.19.0                   pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.2.0.34                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1g               he774522_0    defaults
pefile                    2019.4.18                  py_0    defaults
pip                       20.1.1                   py37_1    defaults
pycryptodome              3.8.2            py37he774522_0    defaults
pyinstaller               3.6              py37h62dcd97_5    defaults
python                    3.7.7                h81c818b_4    defaults
pywin32                   227              py37he774522_1    defaults
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                 py37_1000    defaults
setuptools                47.3.1                   py37_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.32.3               h2a8f88b_0    defaults
tqdm                      4.46.1                     py_0    defaults
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4    defaults
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_2    defaults
wheel                     0.34.2                   py37_0    defaults
wincertstore              0.2                      py37_0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4    defaults
```

then

```
pyinstaller -F path/to/your/python-file -p path/to/your/venv/python.exe
```

Comment: It does solve my problem so it answers my question, thanks!

Comment: _`pip install opencv-python` not `conda install opencv`_ Why? Can you explain things?

Comment: i dont exactly know why, but when i use "conda install opencv", program didnt work, then i google the problem, most answers talked about environment problems, and i ckecked the opencv version, and remembered i used to installing opencv by "pip install opencv-python", then i tried, and the program worked, and i also checked the opencv version, it was different from the version of opencv installed by "conda install opencv".

Comment: Same for me. I had to manually track down matching versions and your answer put me in the right direction

Comment: it also resolved my problem. i still don't know why.